# Does order of conditions matter with multiple conditions in a while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop, conditional-statements

I was not able to find the answer to this question. I was working on an insertion sort method and it wouldn't properly execute:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void insertionSort(T[] array) {
    int length = array.length;
    T temp;
    for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) { //start of unsorted
        temp = array[i]; //save the element
        int j = i-1;
        while (temp.compareTo(array[j]) < 0 && j >= 0) { // while temp is less than array[j]
            array[j+1] = array[j]; 
            j--;
        } //end of while
        array[j+1] = temp; //as soon as temp is greater than array[j], set array[j] equal to temp
    }
}
```

This returned an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` on the while loop line, but when I switched the conditions in the while loop around to this:

```
while (j >= 0 && temp.compareTo(array[j]) < 0)
```

it worked. I didn't think in Java the order of conditions in a while loop mattered to the program? This is very strange to me, as I've never seen or heard of order mattering in a statement with `&&` since I assumed that the two while loop lines were equivalent.  I was stuck wondering this for a while and couldn't find an answer.

Can someone explain why this is so?

Comment: `&&` will not evaluate the second expression if the first one evaluates to `false`. Read the [first line of the definition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.23).

Comment: conditions are evaluated left to right. java uses short circuit logic. for an AND operation, if the the left condition is false then it will not evaluate the condition on the right.

Comment: This *compiles* just fine.  I'm willing to be it doesn't *run* correctly.

Comment: As for the "why", performance is one reason (no need to keep evaluating if you already know what the result will be.)  But your exact scenario is another reason.  If it always evaluated both, then you couldn't make your safety check to ensure `j>=0` on the same line as where you check `array[j]`, because it would always try to check `array[j]` even if it was out of bounds.  But by short-circuiting, it doesn't have to try to make the check you know will fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditions are evaluated left to right.

Initially, for case `j=-1`, your code wasn't evaluating the second condition because the first one was throwing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception.

```
while (temp.compareTo(array[j]) < 0 && j >= 0)
```

However when you switched the conditions like this:

```
while (j >= 0 && temp.compareTo(array[j]) < 0)
```

then for the same case (`j=-1`), since first condition becomes `false`, then regardless of the second value, the whole condition will always be false; and so the second condition won't be evaluated and hence no exception in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider the following example:

```
boolean b = Condition_1 && Condition_2;
```

Now if the Condition_1 is always false then whatever the value of Condition_2, b will always be false. So when first condition is false of an 'and' then no need to check the value of second condition that is what exactly happened here.

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly error if you use the condition `while (temp.compareTo(array[j]) < 0 && j >= 0)`
In Java, it checks condition `&&` first and then checks `||` after.
In the condition `&&` it checks in the order.
Therefore, in your case `while (temp.compareTo(array[j]) < 0 && j >= 0)`, it check this condition `temp.compareTo(array[j])` firstly. If `j` out of the array index, ==> you get error

When you change the condition to `while (j >= 0 && temp.compareTo(array[j]) < 0)`, it check `j>=0` firstly, if `j = -1` the program cannot go further.