# Why does changing the order of conditions in a while loop affect the number of passing test cases?

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I wrote this code, which passes all the test cases

```java
//passes 1100/1100 cases
while (slow != null && slow.next != null && fast != null && fast.next != null) {
    fast = fast.next.next;
    slow = slow.next
}
```

On the other hand, this code does not, but seems to be very similar.

```java
//passes 1/1100 cases
while (slow != null && slow.next != null && fast.next != null && fast != null) {
    fast = fast.next.next;
    slow = slow.next
}
```

I just noticed that just by changing the order of condition statements in while(), the number of test cases that pass changes. Why is it so?

Comment: please paste code as text, not images. see http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: If `fast == null` is true then access `fast.next` will throw NPE. So checking `fast.next` _before_  `fast == null` is a problem. See: [Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: But please [edit] and add the code AS TEXT. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: also see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42523442/does-order-of-conditions-matter-with-multiple-conditions-in-a-while-loop even though I already posted a better (imo) answer.

Answer (score 2):

Java `if`-statements use something called [short-circuit evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logical-operator-short-circuiting), where if there is an `&&` where the first condition is `false`, or an `||` where the first condition is `true`, then it *will not evaluate the rest of the condition*, because it already knows what the result will be. If there is an `&&` and the first statement is `false`, then it doesn't matter what the rest of the statements evaluate to, since the whole thing is false, and vice-versa if there is an `||` and the first statement is true.

A second issue is that if an object is `null`, then calling any method or accessing any property of the function will throw a [NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). This can be avoided by checking if an object is `null` before using it in cases where you know it might be `null`. In your linked list, evidently you are concerned that a node might be `null`, so you check before accessing its `next`.

These two combine together in your example. If you do

```
if (item != null && item.property != null) {}
```

and `item` *is actually null*, then because of short-circuit evaluation, Java will never actually check `item.property` to see if it's `null` as well, because it already knows the combined statement will be false.

Conversely, if you do

```
if (item.property != null && item != null) {}
```

then Java will try to access `item.property`, which will throw a `NullPointerException` if `item` is `null`.

In your case, evidently many of your test cases had situations where `fast` was null at some point. The example where they passed would have avoided calling `fast.next` when `fast` is null because of short-circuit evaluation, whereas the second example never avoids the `NullPointerException`s at all.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed explanation...... i really appreciate it.

Comment: @Dev if this answer helped you, you can click the green checkmark to mark the answer as "accepted"